# Check that an array contains only one object that contains the provided sub-set of keys

Tags: karate

Given the following input:

```
* def list = [{a: 'aaa', b:'bbb'}, {a:'aa', c:'ccc'}]
* def anotherList = [{a: 'aaa', b:'bbb'}, {a:'aa', b:'', c:'ccc'}]
* def msg = {b: '#string'}
```

How to check that `b` key is present only once?

Using:

```
* match list contains '#(^msg)'
```

will validate that there is at least one occurrence of `b` in list.

How to check that there is exactly one occurrence of key `b` in `list` or in `anotherList`? So such check should **pass** for `list` and **fail** for `anotherList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter with a `match` and a `contains` short-cut:

```
* def list = [{ a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb' }, { a: 'aa', c: 'ccc' }]
* def msg = { b: '#string' }
* def fun = function(x){ return karate.match(x, '#(^msg)').pass }
* def filt = karate.filter(list, fun)
* match filt == '#[1]'
```